# How to calculate total working hours in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-3.1

I created the following model:

```
class Timesheet(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False, verbose_name="Data")
    entry = models.TimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False, verbose_name="Hora Entrada")
    lunch = models.TimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name="Início do Almoço")
    lunch_end = models.TimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name="Fim do Almoço")
    out = models.TimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False, verbose_name="Hora de Saída")
```

This is then returned in a table, that has an extra field called "Total Hours", in which I need to calculate the total worked hours. Each entry refers to the same day.

And I have the following view:

```
def timesheet(request):
    c = Timesheet.objects.all()
    context = {'c': c}
    return render(request, "tracker/timesheet.html", context)
```

The calculation I need to do is: `(out - entry) - (lunch_end - lunch)`.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: I assume it is `(out - entry) + (lunch_end - lunch)`?

Comment: No, it really `(out - entry) - (lunch_end - lunch)`, as the lunch time should subtracted from the whole day of work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can [**`.annotate(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#annotate) each `Timesheet` object with:

```
from django.db.models import DurationField, ExpressionWrapper, F, IntegerField

Timesheet.objects.annotate(
    total_time=ExpressionWrapper(
        ExpressionWrapper(F('out') - F('entry'), output_field=IntegerField()) -
        ExpressionWrapper(F('lunch_end') - F('lunch'), output_field=IntegerField()),
       output_field=DurationField()
    )
)
```

Here each `Timesheet` object that arises from *this* queryset will have an extra attribute `.total_time` which will contain the duration the person worked (so minus the luch break).

Or you can sum all records up with an [**`.aggregate(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#aggregate):

```
from django.db.models import DurationField, ExpressionWrapper, F, IntegerField

Timesheet.objects.aggregate(
    total_time=Sum(
        ExpressionWrapper(F('out') - F('entry'), output_field=IntegerField()) -
        ExpressionWrapper(F('lunch_end') - F('lunch'), output_field=IntegerField()),
       output_field=DurationField()
    )
)['total_time']
```

if the `lunch` and `lunch_end` can be `None`/`NULL`, you can work with [**`Coalesce`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/database-functions/#coalesce):

```
from django.db.models import DurationField, ExpressionWrapper, F, IntegerField, Value
from django.db.models.functions import Coalesce

Timesheet.objects.aggregate(
    total_time=Sum(
        ExpressionWrapper(F('out') - F('entry'), output_field=IntegerField()) -
        Coalesce(ExpressionWrapper(F('lunch_end') - F('lunch'), output_field=IntegerField()), Value(0)),
       output_field=DurationField()
    )
)['total_time']
```

If you thus have `.annotate(…)`d all `Timesheet` records, and passed these as `c`, you can use:

```
{% for ci in c %}
    {{ ci.data }}: {{ ci.entry }} - {{ ci.out }}; {{ ci.total_time }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Should I add this to my view, and then on the table use `<td>{{c.total_time}}</td>`? Or am I thinking wrong on the way this works?

Comment: @JoãodeSousa: you perform the query in the view. Then you can add the queryset (or the result) to the context, and render it in the template.

Comment: Oh wait! I see how this works! This is really great, and really simple when I come to think about it! Thank you so much!

Comment: I tried it and it works! But one problem arose, I didn't think before. It's possible for the lunch hours to be empty (e.g. only working afternoons), then the total time is displayed as None. Should I fix this with an if statement?

Comment: @JoãodeSousa: you can use `Coalesce` to use `0` instead of `NULL` in that case, see edit.

Comment: I get that `'datetime.timedelta' object is not iterable`.

Comment: @JoãodeSousa: well it is indeed not iterable, note that if you *aggregate*, then you get a single `timedelta` which is the total amount of all `Timesheet` records. If you annotate, it is a `.total_time` per `Timesheet` record.

Comment: How can then I loop for each `Timesheet` record the `.total_time`? I'm really lost here.

Comment: @JoãodeSousa: you `.annotate(..)` these, and iterate over the records in the template.